# Use stripe in Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments, nuxt.js

I am a newbie in the programming world. Recently I am encountering difficulty in setting up stripe payment in my nuxt web app. I tried to follow the stripe official document, but it didn't redirect me to the stripe checkout page as expected. Instead, it redirected me to my localhost checkout page while it doesn't exist. I am really appreciated that if you could tell me what I did wrong. Many thanks in advance. Below is my code.

**Frontend**

```
    <template>
    <div>
       <section>
      <div class="product">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/EHyR2nP.png" alt="The cover of Stubborn Attachments" />
        <div class="description">
          <h3>Stubborn Attachments</h3>
          <h5>$20.00</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form action="/create-checkout-session" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" id="checkout-button">Checkout</button>
      </form>
    </section> 
    </div>
</template>
```

**Backend**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())


const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY)


const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:8000';

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: [
      {
        // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
        price: 'price_1XXhOEFTCdQ1tcSK1ALR8CXQ',
        quantity: 1,
      },
    ],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/success`,
    cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}/cancel`,
  });

  res.redirect(303, session.url);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 4002

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`)
})
```

Comment: What is the error? Is it coming from front-end or backend?

Comment: The error should come from backend, it doesn't redirect the user to the stripe checkout page.

Comment: Your backend and frontend code looks good, but the setting on ports does seems suspicious. Have you put debug log to see if your "create-checkout-session" has really kicked in? Also open your Chrome Debug Console and check how your request to your servers look like: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/